# Appending from file geodatabase to ArcSDE fails using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to append a feature class from a file geodatabase to an Arcsde featureclass using this line of code:

`arcpy.Append_management("parcel_copy", sde_path+"parcel" ,"NO_TEST")`

This line works under Python console in ArcMap , but when I execute it under Pyscripter IDE, all the code works fine except the append statement, and it does not return an error.

---

I have tried to isolate the `append` statements in a little script, and it worked, but i still don't understand why it has not worked.

i wonder if i have not deleted a featurelayer refering to a featureclass in SDE, that locks this featureclass, so i cannot append to it.

any explanation?

Comment: Consider using [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join the path and table name in a more robust way.

Comment: the feature classe "parcel_copy"is in the geodatabbase set in the workspace of arcpy, so i can access to this feature class.

Comment: You also may need an edit session open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"parcel_copy" appears to be a layer in the Table of Contents of your map, so will be found when you run the script from ArcMap.

However, in order to let the script (when run outside of ArcMap) know where the data that layer is based on can be found, you will need to either issue [MakeFeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000) before the Append, or more simply reference the path to the dataset in place of the layer name of the Append.